# CURL request does not pass IP address

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, unix, curl

I've created the following file on my **destination server**:
test.php

```
<? 
    echo json_encode($_SERVER);
```

When CURLing to this file from **my computer**(mac):

```
curl -XPOST '<myurl>/test.php'
```

the 'REMOTE_ADDRESS' that is returned is the external IP of **my computer**(as expected). However, when CURLing to this file from my **source server**(through ssh, linux), exactly the same command, the 'REMOTE_ADDRESS' is always the IP of my **destination server**. Somehow, the CURL command on my **source server** does not expose its IP on the other side.

There is no 'X_FORWARDED_FOR' property in the $_SERVER variable.

Is this some CURL configuration i'm missing on my **source server**?

Comment: Do you mean that it shows identical values in REMOTE_ADDRESS and SERVER_ADDRES?

Comment: Yes, REMOTE_ADDRESS contains the same value as SERVER_ADDRESS

Comment: Does the destination server have any NAT or "MASQUERADE" firewall rules?